# JComboBox mutável

Tags: java, jcombobox

Pessoas,

Estou trabalhando em um cadastro de férias.

A pessoa coloca a data inicial e um combo com a quantidade de dias (10,15, 20 e 30)aparece para que ela o complete.

Enquanto não forem lançados 30 dias de ferias para o funcionario a tela não fecha.(A cada iteração soma-se a quantidade da anterior até dar 30)
Mas queria que a quantidade de dias disponiveis no JComboBox fosse alteravel. Por exemplo lancei 20 dias, o jcombobox deveria dar somente a opção de 10. Lancei 15 dias apenas a opção de 15 e lançando 10 dias a opção de 10 e 20.
Contudo não consigo limpar e readicionar valores no combo.

Aparece um erro de NullPointerException

```
if (crt.getSomaQuantidadeFerias(rf.getText(),   ex.getText()) < 30) {
                        int soma = 30 - crt.getSomaQuantidadeFerias(rf.getText(), ex.getText());


                        inicio_ferias.setText("");
                        qtd.setSelectedItem(null);
                        inicio_ferias.setText("");
                        termino_ferias.setText("");
                        tfmes.setText("");
                        try{
                        qtd.removeAllItems();

                        if(soma == 10){
                            qtd.addItem("10");
                            qtd.addItem("20");
                        }else if(soma == 15){
                            qtd.addItem("15");
                        }else if(soma == 20){
                            qtd.addItem("10");
                        }}catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
```

O printStackTrace()

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at view.TelaFerias$4.actionPerformed(TelaFerias.java:439)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
    at view.TelaFerias$2.actionPerformed(TelaFerias.java:385)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Como posso limpar os valores pré-definidos e colocar novos?

Comment: Bem-vindo(a). Você poderia criar um exemplo que seja reproduzível? - [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Bom pelo erro essa linha seria importante analizar:

```
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
```

diz que o valor selecionado esta nullo,

tente tirar essa linha `qtd.setSelectedItem(null);` e o `qtd.removeAllItems();` não precisa estar dentro do try...

de uma olhada também se esse metodo `crt.getSomaQuantidadeFerias` esta pedindo como parametro duas strings e retornando um inteiro corretamente.